# Script error with require-2.1.1.min.js in Phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm trying to build an app I've built with Phonegap. When I try to emulate the app in my Android Virtual Device, the app doesn't load because of the following error...

[image]

```
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror at file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/require/require-2.1.1.min.js:31
```

The same project compiles perfectly for iOS...

The console closes with the message:
`File is Out of sync`

Does anyone have an idea how this issue can be tackled?

Comment: it could be an issue with allowed domains, do you have setting such as: <access origin="*" /> ?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, in the JSON file, there is a header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", but nothing more...

Comment: Any resolution here? I'm having the same error but hoping not to have to go the optimization route...

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap and require.js are not really a match made in heaven, it caused a lot of problems with my projects too.

To overcome this, you could optimize your javascript-files using the [requireJS optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). In this way, all the javascript gets compiled (and optionally minified) into one file.

To get started, install it (if you're using node): `npm install -g requirejs`

You can tell the optimizer which files to optimize through a build-config.js file, like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    dir: "../js-built",
    paths: {
        jquery: "some/other/jquery";
        // all the other paths to your modules
    },
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

Instead of listing all the paths in this build-config-file, you can make this a lot easier by referencing your main.js-configuration file (which contains a list of paths to all the modules you are using). Just use the next option in your build-config.js-file:

```
mainConfigFile: '..js/main.js',
```

To disable the minifying, you can pass the next option to the config, makes it a lot easier to debug:

```
optimze: "none"
```

You can find an example-build-config-file with all the options here: [example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)

Finally, to optimze everything, pass the filename for your build-file to the optimizer:

```
node r.js -o build-config.js
```

Include the newly optimzed `main-built.js` in your head-section:

```
<script src="js/lib/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js-built/main-built.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and you're done.